# How should I interpret the sensor_msgs/LaserScan.angle_min?

Tags: lidar, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the RPLidar A2 on my ROSbot 2.0 for environment detection.

I am currently trying to implement a side-distance measurer that measures the distance of four sides, let's say NORTH, EAST, SOUTH and WEST. However, rather than being the directions relative to the robot body, I want to measure the sides in exact degrees of 0, 90, 180 and 270, with respect to the initial theta orientation of the robot being 0.

To do this, I implemented a function that takes in a global angle, and based on scan attributes and current yaw, returns the index in ranges that the degree is at.

```
angle_to_index = lambda angle: int( ((angle - (yaw+scan.angle_min)) % (2*math.pi))/scan.angle_increment )
```

Let's assume that the initial orientation is robot facing NORTH. When I request the readings at degree 0 with `angle_to_index(0)`, the readings fit that of the SOUTH direction.

That makes me think, if the `scan.angle_min` value is -3.12, which I suppose is relative to the front of the robot, then `scan.ranges[0]` should return a reading from the back of the vehicle, right? But in this case, it looks like readings around the `scan.angle_min` correspond to the front of the robot, which confused me.

So, how should I interpret the `sensor_msgs/LaserScan.angle_min`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330860/how-should-i-interpret-the-sensor_msgs/laserscan.angle_min?/) by [erugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44431/erugo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the [message definition for `sensor_msgs/LaserScan`](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) specifies, `angle_min` is the start angle of the scan, i.e. equivalent to `ranges[0]`.

However, i.e. all w.r.t. the frame in which the laser scan is published. For the RPLiDAR A2 (and assuming you are using the `rplidar_ros` package), you can see the frame orientation on [this GitHub wiki page](https://github.com/robopeak/rplidar_ros/wiki#how-to-install-rplidar--to-your-robot). Also, `angle_min` [is set](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/blob/master/src/node.cpp#L320) to `0.0`, i.e. along the x-axis.

As to your question: your function is (at least) missing the angle with which your lidar is mounted on your robot. This would allow you to transform this accordingly.

But also note that `angle_min` is actually implementation defined, depending on how you want to send out messages and how the communication with the lidar is specified. most 360°-Lidars actually have `angle_min` as `-M_PI`, RPLiDAR being the exception...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44431/erugo/) on 2019-08-16**:
Hi,

Thanks for the detailed answer.

My LaserScan readings claim that `angle_min: -3.12413907051, angle_increment: 0.0174532923847`, but I did not take into account the static transform between base_link and laser, I assumed publishing that to the nodes would set the frame of `LaserScan.angle_min` in global coordinates.

So I guess instead of using `scan.angle_min`, I should use something like `scan.angle_min + static_yaw_of_laser_wrt_baselink`.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-16**:
Yes, correct. You need to adjust for that static yaw. Also, you are right, `angle_min` [could be different](https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/blob/master/src/node.cpp#L356). Missed that before...

**Comment by [erugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44431/erugo/) on 2019-08-16**:
Got it, thanks. The issue seems fixed with this update. Best.